# Javascript trouble reversing loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

This loop works 100% fine:

```
 for(m = 1; m < splitData.length; m++)
```

This one however throws errors!  (Relating to loop body)

```
for(m = splitData.length; m > 1; m--)
```

The entire chunk of code is:

```
// Success
if (splitData[0] == "1") {
    // DbID, username, msg, date

 for(m = splitData.length; m > 1; m--){
        var splitMsg = splitData[m].split("¬");
        $('#<%=discussionBoard.ClientID %>').prepend('<div class="messageWrapper">
             <div class="messageHead">' + splitMsg[1] + '</div>
             <div class="messageTxt">' + splitMsg[2] + 
             '<div class="messageDetails">' + splitMsg[3] + 
             '</div></div></div>');
 }
```

The first index in splitData is just a 1 or 0 indicating if Ajax returned good data.  I then want to loop through the rest of the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're off-by-one. Remember that the indexes in Javascript are 0-based, which means that they go from `0` to `length - 1`. Try this instead:

```
for (m = splitData.length - 1; m >= 1; m--)
```

Comment: You dont want to check for `>=` to 0 just `>`

Comment: @Raynos: I didn't notice that he wanted to ignore the first element. So, yes, I was off-by-one. :)

Comment: To be the exact reverse of his original loop should it not be m > 0 not m >= 0?

Comment: The most important part would be "m = splitData.length - 1"

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
for(m = splitData.length - 1; m > 0; m--)
```

instead of:

```
for(m = splitData.length; m > 1; m--)
```

Answer (score 1):

`// count from 1 to splitData.length - 1`

`for(m = 1; m < splitData.length; m++)`

`// count from splitData.length to 2`

`for(m = splitData.length; m > 1; m--)`

you want

`for (m =splitData.length = 1; m > 0; m--)`